# automated testing of gadgets

Tags: automated-tests, wso2, opensocial, google-gadget

I'm looking to write a few [gadgets](http://docs.opensocial.org/display/OS/Home) that I will be running in WSO2 [gadget server](http://wso2.com/products/gadget-server/).  Before I start, I would like to understand how I can test the gadgets using an automated test framework.

Can standard web browser automation tests (e.g. selenium) be used for gadgets?  If not, is there any documentation or wiki pages showing how automated gadget testing can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is the best option to do a test automation for gadgets. because it will test from the UI level.

Comment: does anything special need to be done with selenium to test gadgets?

Comment: You can look at sample codes available here, these are few tests written for GS using selenium. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/qa/web-test-framework/gs/